# Homestead: Laravel Web page not available

Tags: php, laravel, vagrant, homestead

i have problem to access url in my homestead. when i access site.com is not available. must add port 8000 to my url site.com:8000

how can i remove the port to access url in browser?

here my homestead.yaml

```
ip: "192.168.10.10"
memory: 2048
cpus: 1
provider: virtualbox

authorize: ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

keys:
    - ~/.ssh/id_rsa

folders:
    - map: C:\Users\Ghali\Dropbox\PJ-Space\laravel
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/PJ-Space

sites:
    - map: pasangjob.backend.app
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/PJ-Space/back-end/laravel/public
    - map: pasangjob.co.id
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/PJ-Space/front-end/public

databases:
    - pasangjob_v4
    # - pasangjob_v4

variables:
    - key: APP_ENV
      value: local

# blackfire:
#     - id: foo
#       token: bar
#       client-id: foo
#       client-token: bar

# ports:
#     - send: 93000
#       to: 9300
#     - send: 7777
#       to: 777
#       protocol: udp
```

and my host

```
192.168.10.10           pasangjob.backend.app
192.168.10.10           pasangjob.co.id
```

Comment: Did you alter your `scripts/homestead.rb` file?

Comment: i'm not change the file

Answer (score 0):

Try doing `vagrant provision` after you configure your `homestead.yaml` file